# link fill full td height in a table

Tags: html, css

I have this situation: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxabmLLf/)

The problem is when i have more content in a link tag. I want to fill the entire table cell (height) for all links.

```
.grid {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.grid td{
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
.grid td a{
   background-color: yellow;
   display:block;
}
        <table class="grid">
    <tr>
        <td>
             <a href="#">
                 content content content contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent content
             </a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">content</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">content</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">content</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">content</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

set *`white-space: nowrap`* css property, you content will not split to other line.

#### Code:

```
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
             <a href="#">
                 content content content contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent content
             </a>
        </td>
```

Update fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wxabmLLf/1/

MDN Documentation about *white-space*:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved through css alone. You need some javascript to do this.

Here is my solution:

once the page is loaded, you can check the maximum height of a td and assign that height to all the link in that particular table.